# Need to improve inefficient macro (Slow formula calculations and find/replace)

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, performance, optimization

I have two different files with almost identical columns. One of them is much larger than the other (one is about 20k rows, the other about 180k), though, and the macro does not run as well on the larger one. So this has led me to believe my code is inefficient. Specifically, when I step into each line by line, the parts that seem to take the longest are the "find and replace", and the formulaR1C1 additions.

I've read that using arrays can improve efficiency, but I'm having a hard time finding the best way to implement them.

Specifically, this portion where I try to remove dollar signs from a string, it seems to take even longer than just using sheet.range.replace(xxx, xx, xx,).

```
'Initial code to remove $ from range  
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lrow As Long
lrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
ws.Range("BG:BG, BI:BI").Replace what:="$", Replacement:="", lookat:=xlPart

'Attempt at improving speed
Dim Array1 As Variant
Set Array1 = ws.Range("BG2:BG" & lrow)
    For Each cell In Array1
        cell.value = Replace(cell.value, "$", "")
    Next cell
Dim Array2 As Variant
Set Array2 = ws.Range("BI2:BI" & lrow)
    For Each cell In Array2
        cell.value = Replace(cell.value, "$", "")
    Next cell
```

Also wondering if I should work on trying to add several different calculations like below to loop through arrays instead of printing directly to the worksheet. These are just some examples of the formulas used.

```
ws.Range("B2:B" & lrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=rc[-1]&""-""&rc[1]"
ws.Range("P2:P" & lrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=rc[1]+rc[2]+rc[3]"
ws.Range("V2:V" & lrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=if(rc[-1]=0,0,rc[-10]/rc[-1])"
ws.Range("AY2:AY" & lrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=rc[-1]*rc[-39]"
wsnetwork.Range("B2:B" & lrow2).FormulaR1C1 = "=XLOOKUP(RC[-1],'Base'!C4,'Base'!C11)"
wsnetwork.Range("D2:D" & lrow2).FormulaR1C1 = "=if(RC[-2] = 0 , RC[-1] , RC[-2])"
wsnetwork.Range("I2:I" & lrow2).FormulaR1C1 = "=iferror(RC[-3] / RC[-1], 0)"
```

Comment: Try setting `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`  and `Application.EnableEvents = False` and `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`. It should improve speed significantly. Remember to return the settings to `True` and `xlCalculationAutomatic` before exiting the macro.

Comment: You have `Range`s, not arrays. Calling `Replace` on every single cell in a range is going to be slower than calling, `.Replace` on the entire range. `ws.Range("BG:BG, BI:BI").Replace what:="$", Replacement:="", lookat:=xlPart` is the way to go.

Comment: And use your `lrow` variable, i.e. `ws.Range("BG2:BG" & lrow & ", BI2:BI" & lrow).Replace what:="$", Replacement:="", lookat:=xlPart`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be more efficient, you need to read the data into array, then do things within array, then backfill array into range. Just like below.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

data = ws.Range("BG1:BG" & ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Value

for i = 2 to ubound(data, 1)
    data(i, 1) = Replace(data(i, 1), "$", "")
next i

ws.Range("BG1:BG" & ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count) = data

data = ws.Range("BI1:BI" & ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Value

for i = 2 to ubound(data, 1)
    data(i, 1) = Replace(data(i, 1), "$", "")
next i

ws.Range("BI1:BI" & ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count) = data
```

Comment: Thank you @zzzcolin! This is what I was looking for. Question, though, is this portion of the code most efficient? 

    `ws.Range("BG1:BG" & ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count) = data`

Would it be better to use another for loop to place the values back onto the worksheet

Something like this? 

    `For i = 2 To UBound(data, 1)
        ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = data(i)
    Next i`

Comment: No need, use batch backfill is faster than fill cell one by one.